# UICollectionView Disappears In UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uistackview

I have two `UICollectionView` and two `UILabel`.

Each `UICollectionView` and `UILabel` are put into a `UIStackView` (distribution set to fill, and the height of the `UICollectionView` set to 75). Then, the two `UIStackViews` are placed into another `UIStackView`. This `mainStackView` is centred to the x and y of the view.

My issue is is that when I run the app, my the `UICollectionViews` disappears, and I have no idea why.

This is what my `viewController` looks like in the storyboard [image]

And this is how it looks when running:
[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like there is open space where you expect the collection views to be. Are you sure the collection views have some content? If you run the app you can use `Debug View Hierarchy` to see everything that is there even if empty. (The button for it looks like two rectangles that are perpendicular and on top of each other a little to the right of the pause button in the debugger strip)

Comment: So I checked it like you said and you're right, the `collectionView` wasn't even in the hierarchy. What should i do then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to set the constraint Anchors (if you're using Anchors) of the `UICollectionView` to `leading`, `trailing`, and the container `UIStackView` needs those as well as `topAnchor`, `bottomAnchor`. Also make sure that everything either has a height set, or has intrinsic content size.
I'll tell you what though - 75% of the time when **I** thought a `UIStackView` would make my life easier, it didn't, and added on to development time two-fold. You're using `UIStackViews` inside `UIStackViews` so expect extra complexity. The result you're trying to get could also be achieved via regular old Anchor constraints and could be much simpler. Throw it together in Playgrounds and see what I mean. I'd be happy to help if you need it with that.

If you still have issues and if you still want to go the UIStackView route, please update your question with code or indicators around constraints. Good luck!

Comment: FANTASTIC ADVICE. I'm sure it will work. I suspect UIStackView is why I'm not seeing my UICollectionView. Apple steers people to use UIStackView whenever possible (I saw in some docs) but if this is where it can end up, I don't need the headache. Not that hard to constrain a couple of views.

Comment: @clearlight Apple also steers people towards Storyboards when in fact Storyboards are *terrible* for teams as they don't handle merge conflicts gracefully at all, and can get unreasonably complicated and unwieldy.